# Git: Created a local and remote repositories, how can I use the files I pushed to the remote repository?

Tags: git, repository

I've already created two repositories - a local(on my machine) and a remote (from a live server). The remote one is a bare repository. The files are all HTML files.

Now my question is, how can I use those files I pushed to the remote one so that they may be accessible through the web? Should I create another repository from the live server and pull that one from a bare repository? Or will symlink work for this?

Comment: You need to use [git daemon](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-daemon.html) to expose your repository through http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by cloning my remote repo.

e.g.

my remote repo is located in

```
/home/user/repo/mywebsite.git
```

so inside my

```
/var/www/mywebsite
```

I did `git clone /home/user/repo/mywebsite.git .`

Then if I push to my remote repo which is `/home/user/repo/mywebsite.git`,
I'll just do `git pull` in `/var/www/mywebsite`

I hope this will help those having same issue as me because git-daemon didn't work well for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a bare repository on the server, then it won't contain a working tree with the files visible. This is typically what you want for a remote store.

However, if you want to serve the files via a webserver, you need to have access to the working tree, and you are right - cloning the bare repo to the served web directory will allow you (and the webserver) to access the files.

If you want to navigate the git repo itself via the web (i.e. look at the logs etc) then you'll need to install git-daemon and point it to the bare git repo.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best solution is to configure git push hook script on server, which will clone/update files from bare repo (guess, master branch) to your WEB sources folder.

Comment: I've already tried configuring a hook like this in hooks/post-receive #!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mywebsite git checkout -f. But everytime I push, I'm getting a "Text file busy" error. Do you have any idea what caused that error?

Comment: Is your `/var/www/mywebsite` a local git repo? Did you make pull firstly? Did you try to login as `git` (or `gitosis`) user and to make `git checkout` from /var/www/mywebsite directory?

Comment: `/var/www/mywebsite` is in the live server. Just the same server where my remote repo is located.

Comment: So, you have to clone your repo into `/var/www/mywebsite` and then you would be able to checkout into it using git post-receive hook.
BTW, if they are in same server - u can clone from local repo without `git`, `ssh` or `https` protocols. This works much faster and avoids problem with keys and passwords.